# Is this analysis of algorithm correct?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, code-analysis, asymptotic-complexity

Imagine that there's a vector of integers, going from the position -infinite..2..1..0..1..2..+infinite. 
Only one position will contain an integer value 1, the others will contain 0, the algorithm will find the position that contains the integer value of 1.
Consider "verifyDoor" method O(1).

I've come with this solution and I would like to know if my analysis is correct.

I've came to the following result: 
T(n)=8n+10
T(n)=O(n)

Here it is:
[image]

Code:

```cpp
int findDoor(int[] wall){
    if(verifyDoor(0)){              // 1
        return 0;                   // 1
    }

    int p =1;                       // 1
    while(1){                       // n
        if(verifyDoor(p)){          // n+1
            return p;               // n+1
        }else{                      // n+1
            if(p>0){                // n+1
                p=p*-1;             // n+1
            }else{                  // n+1
                p=(p*-1)+1;         // n+1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Consider "n" the vector length
T(n) = 8n+10 (this would be the total of how many times each instruction would be ran)
T(n) = O(n)

Comment: Why post an image of the code rather than the code itself?

Comment: Where do you get 8n+10?

Comment: John, the code doesn't need changes, only an analysis, I though that an image would be enough, but I've updated with the code.

Comment: Ergonaut, this would be the formula of how many times all the instructions would be ran, I've calculated how many times each line would be ran and the result would be the sum of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(n)? What is n? You need to define n.

If n is the distance of the door from position 0, then yes the complexity is O(n).

This is because, for a door at position i, the algorithm visits each position in [-|i|, |i|] once (except for -i if i is positive), and there are only 2|i| or 2|i| + 1 such positions. Each visit takes O(1) time.

Comment: Sorry, I guess n would be the vector length, and I've counted how many times each instruction would be ran, that's the 8n+10.

Comment: @user4857867 But you described the vector as having infinite length, so that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Oh, that's true! I guess I shouldn't be counting how many time the instructions would be ran, only consider its complexity. Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is O(n), however counting it as 8n + 10 usually does not make much sense as some operation requires much more time than another and you do not even know about it.

For example `}else{` does not always require additional time, because some compilers just implements "goTo", no matter if it jumps to "else" branch or after the if branch...

Or declaring variable can cost 100 timer more than give value to it etc.

Comment: Also, not all 8 lines of code in the loop execute on each iteration, so the detailed analysis is wrong anyway.

Comment: But considering each simple operation to be +1, and the size of the vector is n, would my analysis be correct? Also I'm counting the number of instruction.

Comment: Bill The Lizard you are correct, I've considered the worst case scenario, but even in the worst case it wouldn't run all lines everytime, so I don't know how I would calculate it.

Comment: @user4857867 - you dont want to calculate it. What matters is that T(1) = constant part of application is run n-times, therefore T(n)*T(1) = T(n)

Comment: @user4857867 In this case it doesn't matter because the worst case is still just some constant times n, so the final answer still simplifies to O(n). If one of the if statements contained a loop, that would add complexity in that branch and you'd have a different final answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I get it now!

Comment: This is a very misleading answer. You're making the same mistake the asker did by calling the complexity "O(n)" without even defining what "n" is. This is such a common mistake when talking about complexity and this answer only reinforces the idea that what matters is how you count an ultimately constant number of O(1) operations to arrive at O(1), not how to reason about the actual complexity of the algorithm. The entire body of the `while` loop is clearly O(1).  I agree that the asker was reasoning about that incorrectly with the whole "8n + 10" thing, but that's not the point.